# Display text field from Matrix of an Entry Field in Matrix

Tags: matrix, entry, loop, blocks

Question is similar to some others I've looked through but their solutions don't work as there are some differences.

Currently this doesn't output any of the fields I try to access within the internal matrix.

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('sectionHandle').find() %}
    {% for block in entry.matrixHandle.limit(1) %}
        {% for entry in block.entryFieldMatrixHandle.first() %}
            {% for block in entry.entrysMatrixHandle.limit(1) %}
                {{ block.fieldHandle }}
            {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Not sure if it will solve your problem or not, but your inner `{% for entry` and `{% for block` loops are overwriting the output `entry` and `block` variables that are defined in the outer loops. You'll want to rename them to something else.

Comment: Yep! Thanks! Didn't realize that's how it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of problems with your current code – for one, you're (as Brad mentions in the comments above) doing some variable overwriting by reusing the `entry` and `block` names. Also, you're attempting to do a `for` loop on the result from a call to `first()`, which won't work (`first()` returns a single element, not an array).

In any case, I'd suggest getting rid of all the `for` loops (you're looping on a resultset with a single element in each of your inner loops), in an attempt to make the code a tad more clear.

Something like this should work:

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('sectionHandle') %}
    {% set outerBlock = entry.matrixHandle.first() %}
    {% set outerBlockEntry = outerBlock ? outerBlock.entryFieldMatrixHandle.first() %}
    {% set innerBlock = outerBlockEntry ? outerBlockEntry.entrysMatrixHandle.first() %}
    {{ innerBlock ? innerBlock.fieldHandle }}
{% endfor %}
```

That's a lot of `{% set %}` statements, though – you could also do this (although I'm honestly not sure which option is more readable):

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('sectionHandle') %}
    {% set block = entry.matrixHandle.first().entryFieldMatrixHandle.first().entrysMatrixHandle.first()|default %}
    {{ block ? block.fieldHandle }}
{% endfor %}
```

Finally, as an alternative approach altogether you could use the [`relatedTo`](https://craftcms.com/docs/relations#the-relatedTo-param) param:

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('sectionHandle') %}

    {% set block = craft.entries.relatedTo({
        sourceElement: entry.matrixHandle.first(),
        field: 'entryFieldMatrixHandle'
    }).first().entrysMatrixHandle.first()|default %}

    {{ block ? block.fieldHandle }}

{% endfor %}
```

None of the above examples are tested, and now my head hurts – but hopefully it'll prove helpful :)

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize the variable name could be change at the beginning of the for loop. I thought it was stuck as "block" and "entry". All set now!